# Filtering the log files from log directories [~/.ros/log and ~/.ros/logs]

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Filtering the log files for one exact session does not seem to be so trivial. There are in fact two of the log directories:

- `~/.ros/log`, which seems to contain one directory per session, but not the node-specific logs
- `~/.ros/logs`, which contains all node and topic-specific logs

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Now, if `~/.ros/logs` does contain relevant information, how to **FILTER** only the logs related to the last session? Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/346246/filtering-the-log-files-from-log-directories-%5B%7E/.ros/log-and-%7E/.ros/logs%5D/) by [sosoup](https://answers.ros.org/users/31227/sosoup/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2020-03-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Generally, logs will be created in `~/.ros/log`. Each of the folders in there corresponds to one session. (each time you started a roscore, either manually or with roslaunch) At the start of the session, the path will be displayed which will look something like this:

`... logging to /home/USER/.ros/log/ad10d67c-6219-11ea-a8a8-207918a17840/roslaunch-host-2444.log`

In this folder, (here `~/.ros/log/ad10d67c-6219-11ea-a8a8-207918a17840`) every node will get a file produced by the logging macros in the sources. https://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Logging.
But there will also be a floder `~/.ros/log/latest`, containing the logs from the last session. It is actually a symlink, you can use it to check, which one was the last session with `ls -l ~/.ros/log/latest`.

---

Originally posted by [ct2034](https://answers.ros.org/users/12141/ct2034/) with karma: 862 on 2020-03-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [luchko](https://answers.ros.org/users/45671/luchko/) on 2020-03-09**:
Hi, juste to be as accurate as possible :

- logs are stored in `$ROS_HOME/log`
  (default is .ros folder in your home
  directory)
- if you want to modify    tis path,
  set `$ROS_LOG_DIR` env.    var.
- each time you start a new    master,
  a new folder is created.    FOlder
  name is a UUID randomly    generated.
  Not particularly user    friendly...
  but ROS also symlink the    current
  (or last) logs directory as
  `$ROS_HOME/log/latest`

If you don't see what you want in there, 2 hints :

- I can't remember the default, but I
  think you have to set `output="log"`
  attribute when declaring your node in
  your launchfile
- You can set
  `$ROSCONSOLE_CONFIG_FILE` and
  `$ROSCONSOLE_FORMAT` env. variables
  to match your needs (see 
  [ros wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/EnvironmentVariables)

**Comment by [sosoup](https://answers.ros.org/users/31227/sosoup/) on 2020-03-09**:
Thanks @ct2034 and @luchko.
But my issue is still not clear. As I have mentioned there are couple of directories:

1. ${ROS_LOG_DIR}/**log**
    2. ${ROS_LOG_DIR}/**logs**

While the explanation for ***/log*** directory is clear. What the ***/logs*** directory contains?

**Comment by [ct2034](https://answers.ros.org/users/12141/ct2034/) on 2020-03-09**:
I dont think i have ever seen a `${ROS_LOG_DIR}/logs` dir. what does it contain?

**Comment by [sosoup](https://answers.ros.org/users/31227/sosoup/) on 2020-03-10**:
A quick look at the `$ echo $ROS_LOG_DIR` gives me `~/.ros/logs` which would mean that this is the default log directory. However, I could see another `~/.ros/log` directory along side and that might be because, (as @luchko also mentioned) of the ROS launch attribute for logging, `output="log|screen"`,  if 'log', the stdout/stderr output will be sent to a log file in `$ROS_HOME/log`. [ROS launch node tag](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/node).

**Comment by [ct2034](https://answers.ros.org/users/12141/ct2034/) on 2020-03-11**:
does this answer your question?